# Device error, Buffersize 0

Tags: boot, uefi

So guys, the image below basically shows:

```
Unexpected return from initial red: Device error, buffersize 0
Failed to load image \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi: Device Error
```

[image]

This problem started to occur after my Lenovo Netbook fell from my bag. Sometimes, the Os is loaded and almost every time, it happens like this. Either the Os might be corrupted or something-something that I don't know. You guys help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Disk broken at 95%. When you have the chance of booting, backup (if you didn't), then  you can try to check the disk with `badblocks` booting from a Live USB.